# Xtext Validator creating Errors

Tags: java, xtext, xtend

I was wondering if there is a general strategy that can be applied to show errors (or warnings etc.) in the validator.

I know there is the `error` function, that take arguments like:

- `message`
- `source`
- `feature`
- and others...

Is it possible to call this function in a generic way that works at least most of the time? I know that there are people that call the function like:
`error("MyMessage", eObject.eContainer(), eObject.eContainingFeature(), ...)`, however, this puts the error in the wrong place most of the times. Isn't it possible to just add an Error to the `eObject` without caring about the features and stuff?

When I call it like this: `error("MyMessage", eObject, eObject.eContainingFeature(), ...)` I get an Exception, because the feature and the eObject does not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer. You can set the feature to `null`.

So you can call the function like:
`error("MyMessage", eObject, null, ...)`